# TensorFlow Bazel Configuration

Tags: configuration, tensorflow, bazel

We are using a GTX 1080
with Ubuntu 16.04,
we installed CUDA 7.5, cudnn v5.1
We used compute capabilities 6.1

The 16.04 installation of CUDA was
made using the 15.04 Ubuntu version
and some very minor changes suggested by 
https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/NVIDIA-CUDA-with-Ubuntu-16-04-beta-on-a-laptop-if-you-just-cannot-wait-775/

All this seems to have worked fine.

In trying to install tensorflow from sources, per Google's
instructions for anything other than the default configuration,
we have run into a problem.
We do not know if this is something wrong on your end or Google's.
If you cannot help us, can you refer us to someone who can?

Thank you.

## Below is the relevant run from a script file, with embedded special characters edited out.

```
laefsky@main:~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/tensorflow file://main/home/laefsky/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/tensorflow(tensorflow) laefsky@main: ~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/tensorflow laefsky@main ~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/tensorflow$ ./configure
~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/tensorflow ~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/tensorflow
Please specify the location of python. [Default is /home/laefsky/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/bin/python]: 
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Google Cloud Platform support? [y/N] N
No Google Cloud Platform support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Found possible Python library paths:
  /home/laefsky/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Please input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is [/home/laefsky/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages]

/home/laefsky/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with GPU support? [y/N] y
GPU support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Please specify which gcc should be used by nvcc as the host compiler. [Default is /usr/bin/gcc]: 
Please specify the Cuda SDK version you want to use, e.g. 7.0. [Leave empty to use system default]: 
Please specify the location where CUDA  toolkit is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is /usr/local/cuda]: 
Please specify the Cudnn version you want to use. [Leave empty to use system default]: 
Please specify the location where cuDNN  library is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is /usr/local/cuda]: 
Please specify a list of comma-separated Cuda compute capabilities you want to build with.
You can find the compute capability of your device at: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus.
Please note that each additional compute capability significantly increases your build time and binary size.
[Default is: "3.5,5.2"]: "6.1"
INFO: Starting clean (this may take a while). Consider using --expunge_async if the clean takes more than several minutes.
......
ERROR: /home/laefsky/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl:442:18: function 'repository_rule' does not exist.
ERROR: com.google.devtools.build.lib.packages.BuildFileContainsErrorsException: error loading package 'external': Extension file '@local_config_cuda//cuda:build_defs.bzl' may not be loaded from a WORKSPACE file since the extension file is located in an external repository.
Configuration finished
laefsky@main:~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/tensorflow[]7;file://main/home/laefsky/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/tensorflow(tensorflow) []0;laefsky@main: ~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/tensorflow[[01;32mlaefsky@main[[00m:[[01;34m~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/tensorflow$ logout
```

Comment: I got it working on 1080 with cuda 8 and default compute capabilities

Comment: Also, Pascal-based cards like 1080 are not compatible with CUDA 7.5